# libgdx stopping running music with class

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm working on a little Android Game with libGDX.
The structure is as follows:

Main > Screen:Splashscreen > Screen:MainMenu > Screen: Settings or GameScreen

I have a Preference for the state of music(if running "music" is true).
If the music is true the music starts in the MainMenu.
Now the user should be abled to turn the music on and off in the Settings Screen.
To manage the music I made a class called MusicPlayer.
The Code:

MainMenu:

```
public class StartScreen implements Screen {

   MusicPlayer musicPl;

   Preferences scorepref;
   boolean music;
   (...)

   @Override
   public void show() {

       (...)
       scorepref = Gdx.app.getPreferences("Highscore");

       musicPl = new MusicPlayer();

       music = scorepref.getBoolean("music");

       if(music){
           musicPl.play();
       }
   }
   @Override
   public void dispose() {

       musicPl.dispose();

   }
}
```

Settings:

```
public class SettingScreen implements Screen {

    Preferences scorepref;

    //Setting Values
    boolean tut = false;
    boolean music = false;
    boolean sounds = false;
    int theme = 0;
    //

    MusicPlayer musicPl;

    int touchX = 0;
    int touchY = 0;
    boolean touchD = false;
    boolean touchU = false;

    @Override
    public void show() {

        (handling Input and setting touchX,touchY,touchD and touchU)
        (...)
        musicPl = new MusicPlayer();
        scorepref = Gdx.app.getPreferences("Highscore");

    }
    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {


        tut = scorepref.getBoolean("tut");
        music = scorepref.getBoolean("music");
        sounds = scorepref.getBoolean("sounds");
        (...)

        //if Touched
        if(touchD == true && touchU == true){
            touchD = false;
            touchU = false;
            //wo?
            Vector3 posn = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(),Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
            camera.unproject(posn);

        if(){
            (...)
        } else if (posn.x >= -192 && posn.x <= 192 && posn.y <= 53 && posn.y >= -75) {
            if(music){
                music = false;
                scorepref.putBoolean("music", music);
                scorepref.flush();
                musicPl.stop(); //Error line 206 is here
            } else {
                music = true;
                scorepref.putBoolean("music", music);
                scorepref.flush();
                musicPl.play();
            }
        } (...)
        } else if (posn.x >= -344 && posn.x <= -248 && posn.y <= 543 && posn.y >= 463) {
            ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new StartScreen());
        }

        //var speichern
        scorepref.putBoolean("tut", tut);
        scorepref.putBoolean("music", music);
        scorepref.putBoolean("sounds", sounds);
        scorepref.flush();


   }
   @Override
   public void dispose() {

       musicPl.dispose();

   }
}
```

MusicPlayer:

```
public class MusicPlayer{

    Music menuMusic;
    boolean isrunning;
    Preferences scorepref;

    public void play (){
        scorepref = Gdx.app.getPreferences("Highscore");

        if(scorepref.getBoolean("running") == true){

        } else {
            menuMusic = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("Theme.mp3"));
            menuMusic.setLooping(true);
            scorepref.putBoolean("running", true);
            scorepref.flush();
            menuMusic.play();

        }

   }

    public void stop(){
        scorepref = Gdx.app.getPreferences("Highscore");
        scorepref.putBoolean("running", false);
        scorepref.flush();
        menuMusic.stop();   //Error line 33 is here

    }

    public void dispose(){
        menuMusic.dispose();
    }



}
```

My Problem:
When I am in the Settings Screen the tunring on and off is working fine.
When I turn the music on and go back to the MainScreen the music is still playing. So far so good.
But when I return to the SettingsScreen with running music and I want to turn it off the App crashes.

I think the crash is caused by the stop method, because the MusicPlayer doesn't know what to stop. But how can I tell him or how can i solve this problem with a different technique?

Thanks for helping.

P.S.
Here is the error I get, when I run the App on the desktop:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at de.hatgames.canone.MusicPlayer.stop(MusicPlayer.java:33)
    at de.hatgames.canone.SettingScreen.render(SettingScreen.java:206)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
    at de.hatgames.canone.CanoneMain.render(CanoneMain.java:26)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:215)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
```

CanoneMain.java:26 is just this:

```
super.render();
```

Comment: Please add the error log you're receiving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you return to SettingScreen you create a new MusicPlayer instance each time.

```
musicPl = new MusicPlayer();
```

The `Music` member is only instanciated when `play()` is called:

```
menuMusic = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("Theme.mp3"));
```

That is why menuMusic is null when you call `stop()` before calling `play()`

There are several solutions. You can make the MusicPlayer static and global accesable.

Or you can make sure MusicPlayer is only instanitated once like this:

```
if(musicPl == null) {
musicPl = new MusicPlayer();
}
```

But this will only work when you make sure that SettingsScreen is only instantiated once.

Good topics to read are probably singleton and factory pattern since this case will often occur when programming games.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally using a [Singleton](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton) for the music player as part of it being a global object will be helpful.